# Show percent only if is 'on_sale' Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this product loop for woocommerce

```
<?php global
  $woocommerce;
    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
    $sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
    $percent = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    $marca = $product->get_attribute( 'marcas' );
?>              
<?php echo $percent; ?>
```

But i want to show this ($percent) only if product is really on_sale, to be able to put on the same list both types of products, on_sale & not on_sale without errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if item is on sale like such

```
$is_on_sale = $product->is_on_sale();
if ( $is_on_sale ) {
  //display sale percent
  ...
}else{//product not on sale
  //display regular price 
  ...
}
```

Docs https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1461-1482

Comment: Can you help me with another thing? how I add a <style></style> in this IF and ELSE?

Comment: There are multiple way you can do it. One way is to give the elements a class and if its on sale style it accordingly.  (only add the class if its on sale). Another way would be to echo the style as such: echo '<style>enter here </style>';